# Vscode+arduino : Where to find the "arduino.json" parser?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to upload a new program into my ESP8266 but I want to do this OTA like I do it with arduino's IDE successfully.

I have vscode + arduino's extension installed.

I guess the "arduino.json" is read by vscode before sending program.
I set the "port" field `"port": "192.168.x.xxx",`
Now I want to set the password field too, but I don't know how it is supposed to be named ("password" or "auth" doesn't seems to work!)

So where can I find the code that parse the "arduino.json" file and pass the parameters to espota.py file execution?
(I know that espota.py is waiting the password in the field `--auth="xxx"`